# PowerShell: Compare 2 columns in same csv

Tags: powershell

I have seen several examples of using PowerShell to compare columns in 2 separate csv files, but is there a way to compare 2 columns in the same csv, looping through each record to find the matching records? The result would be to create a new column outputting the matching value. If no match, then the output in the new column would be nothing or zero. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) (substitute the column names of interest for `Col1` and `Col2`, and optionally choose a different new column name instead of `Match`; pipe to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to re-export back to a CSV file):

**If the column values to be compared are *on the same row*:**

```
Import-Csv in.csv | 
  Select-Object *, 
            @{ Name='Match'; Expression={ if ($_.Col1 -eq $_.Col2) { $_.Col1 } } }
```

---

**If the column values should be compared *across all rows*:**

```
# Load all rows as objects into memory.
$allRows = Import-Csv in.csv

# Create a hash set of all distinct Col1 values.
$col1LookupValues = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
  [string[]] $allRows.Col1,
  [StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
)

$allRows |
  Select-Object *, 
    @{ Name='Match'; Expression={ 
       if ($col1LookupValues.Contains($_.Col2)) { $_.Col2 } 
     } }
```

Note: The use of a [`[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) instance makes the lookups efficient.

If performance isn't a concern and the number of rows is small enough, you could get away with 
`$col1LookupValues = [string[]] $allRows.Col1` and 
`if ($col1LookupValues -contains $_.Col2)`

Comment: mklement0 that is exactly what I needed. Thanks again! You are awesome

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @RaabK; thanks for the nice feedback.